# Django MongoDB QuerySet result Into JSON

Tags: django, mongodb, django-nonrel

I have these models:

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    projectName =models.CharField(max_length = 100,unique=True,db_index=True)
    projectManager = EmbeddedModelField('Users')

class Users(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100,unique=True)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length =100 )
```

I need to return JSON from my view for all Projects objects,I tried json.dumps(Projects.objects.all()) but it did not worked,how do i accomplished it??

**EDIT:**
I used json.dumps(Projects.objects.all().values()) and got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 203, in encode
    chunks = list(chunks)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 436, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 178, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: [{'projectName': u'HELLO', 'projectManager': {u'id': u'4eb3b792b990a24e49f6bb26', u'name': u'anshul', u'designation': u'programmer', u'teams': []}, '
id': u'4eb3b7d0e814520db4000000'}] is not JSON serializable
```

Now i am getting the result what i want but why is this giving me error as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querysets are not serializable. You could try to use list(self.objects) instead self.objects to force the queryset to be processed as a list. In your case try something like this

```
json.dumps(list(Projects.objects.all().values()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Jason.dumps-ing the result of [Queryset.values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values).

Comment: Dougal Please check my edit and see if you can help me......I think your answer is really close to what i want

Comment: @icewind is right -- you want to dump the list versions of Queryset.values(), to make a list of dictionaries (rather than an object that kind of acts like a list of dictionaries).